# Executing multiple command line with fixed interval and returning result log

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am trying to run a command file which 
1)opens a certain directory eg c:\new_folder
2)runs a command eg main xxx.js xyz
3)takes the xyz from a column in a excel file
4)runs the command for 2 mins and presses x on the keyboard to end the command (This is needed to end the command I am executing) and then return the text that was generated while running the command.

I need to run this command for 100s of times for the same command with different values of xyz from the excel column.

I belive a way to do this is to create a batch file with
main xxx.js xyz1
main xxx.js xyz2
main xxx.js xyz3
......

I don't know how to have the batch file fetch data from an excel table. Though this can be rectified by pasting the data in notepad but I don't know how to have each command run for 2 mins ( in c:new_folder) and then have a keyboard press of button 'x' and then return the results in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to have the batch file fetch data from an Excel table.

I could be wrong but I believe that this level of interaction isn't possible with vanilla batch commands.

> I don't know how to have each command run for 2 mins [...] and then have a keyboard press of button 'x' and then return the results in a text file.

- Regarding delay, you will probably need to use the *Sleep* or  *Timeout* commands, although there are [more options](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php).
- The ">" sign can be used to redirect batch file output to a text file ([this Stack Overflow answer shows the basic format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19878136/3395469), though you might wish to use variables).
- To the best of my knowledge it isn't possible to send keyboard strokes in vanilla batch alone.

**Note**

Honestly, I would recommend something more advanced like [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-scripting?view=powershell-5.1) or [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), especially since you have requirements that vanilla batch likely doesn't support. Both can potentially have some integration with batch files (if you like) or can be stand-alone solutions themselves. Both are more complex than vanilla batch (though Python arguably has the easiest learning curve of all three) and both PowerShell and Python have libraries which have the ability to read Excel files.